# Combine two columns of table into one in SQL

Tags: sql

I would like to combine two columns(both from different table) into one column.

As shown below, both are expiry date and I would like them to be combined. Either one column will be present. If one is present, the other will not be present. But at times, both will not be present at the same time.  I have looked at concat in sql but it is used to combine.

Need some guidance on this.

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at the `COALESCE` function. `SELECT COALESCE(Expiry, Expiration_date) AS expiration`.

Comment: `Union All` it can do too..

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result? (Note that most people here want formatted text, not images...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server can update the blanks in Expiry column as NULLs then you can do this

```
ISNULL(Expiry,Expiration_date)
```

Comment: Isnull use only in `Sql Server` use general Ansi syntax.. `Coalesce`

Answer (score 1):

Check if the first exists then take it else take the second one: like below:

```
select if(Expiry!='',Expiry, Expiration_date) as expiry from table
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for!